# .htaccess rewriterule change a word in a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to change this url

```
http://airsviluppo.it/lapolverosa/room/standard-room-one-king-bed/
```

To this

```
http://airsviluppo.it/lapolverosa/casali/standard-room-one-king-bed/
```

By htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /lapolverosa/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /lapolverosa/index.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^room\/+?$ casali\/
</IfModule>
```

But doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .htaccess instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /lapolverosa/
    RewriteRule ^room/(.*)$ casali/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Comment: does not works, in the rewriting the result is : http://airsviluppo.it/lapolverosa/casali/ and if I write casali/$2 the result is : http://airsviluppo.it/premium-room-two-single-beds/casali